# i run shell command in spring boot, but process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) dont run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, centos7, runtime.exec

i run follow code in spring boot and java,but process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) don't run in spring boot application.in pure java application is fine. in spring boot, it don't report the exception or error. Can you help me?

```
public String convetor(String videoInputPath,String basepath) {
    File output = new File("/root/output.txt");
    File error = new File("/root/error.txt");
    File tmp = new File(videoInputPath);
    String des = tmp.getName();
    String[] filename = des.split("\\.");
    String dest = basepath+filename[0] + ".ts";

    System.out.println(videoInputPath);
    List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
    command.add("ffmpeg");
    command.add("-i");
    command.add(videoInputPath);
    command.add("-vcodec");
    command.add("copy");
    command.add("-vbsf");
    command.add("h264_mp4toannexb");
    command.add(dest);
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Process process = null;
    String cmd = "ffmpeg -i " + videoInputPath + "-vcodec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb "+dest;
    try {
        System.out.println("==============");
        builder.redirectOutput(output);
        builder.redirectError(error);
//            process = builder.start();
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        System.out.println("++++++++++++");
        InputStreamReader isr = new  InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String lineRead;
        while ((lineRead = br.readLine()) != null) {

        }
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dest;

}`
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the full path of ffmpeg in cmd?

Comment: any error messages or stack traces?

Comment: no any error messages, it‘s very strange....

Comment: i run in pure java application is correct.....the same code

Comment: thanks, @SidMalani, i use absolute path, it run ,thank u very much

Comment: From the code you posted it does not seem so. Can you type "which ffmpeg" this will give you full path for that binary and then use the full path in your spring boot code and let us know if it works?

Comment: i have run the program using @SidMalani 's method, thanks. Using full path is fine